# what files to include with compiled f2py extension on Mac

Tags: python, numpy, f2py

I want to send somebody my compiled fortran extension on a Mac (compiled with f2py and gfortran).

Problem is that it doesn't work on other Macs unless they also instal xcode (2 GB, yikes!) and gfortran. So apparently there are some additional files missing when I just send the compiled extension.

Does anybody know what other files to include or (better) how to compile a fortran extension without needing to send any additional files?

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you compile a module with f2py, it essentially creates a dynamic library (.so) which uses your system libraries. For instance, on my computer, the linking step is,

```
gfortran [...]  -lpython2.7 -lgfortran -o ./my_f2py_module.so
```

Therefore, if you want to be able to execute the resulting f2py module on a different computer (assuming the same architecture), `libpython2.7.so` and `libgfortran.so` should be available there.

I don't know much about OS/X deployment, but I think you should

1. use a compiler present by default on Mac (i.e. clang), which should work with f2py. Or alternatively install gfortran on both systems.
2. make sure you link to the same version of python in both cases

Also use `ldd ./my_f2py_module.so` to list all the libraries that it is linked to. If some of them cannot be found on the current system, you will also see it with this command.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any way to statically link libpython2.7 and liggfortran when running f2py so that I don't have to distribute them with mky_f2py_module.so file that I am creating? I have found some discussion about this at different sites, but no clear direction on how to do that.